# How to auto share to Google+ when share or like from Facebook?

Tags: automation, sharing, facebook, google-plus

I love both sites but get tired quickly to double my time doing the `share` jobs e.g. like button, share button, ... on both site.

Is there a way to `share` in one site, says facebook, and that will be posted automatically in the other site, says google+?

Answer (score 3):

This is not yet possible by any way even using any software also as the API for Google+ is not yet released by google. You have to wait for it. Dont search for it.

Comment: But Facebook does have an API, so it's technically possible to post from Google+ to Facebook (but not vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to share from Google+ to Facebook:

[Rob McGee (formerly Agent G)](http://gplus.sagg.im/)

By connecting with a special Google+ contact, you can get your public Google+ posts to be also posted to Identi.ca, Twitter, and/or Facebook.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though, does it? Although it _is_ an answer to this question: [posting in google+ that is automatically reposted on Facebook](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23677)

Comment: "a way to share in one site, says facebook, and that will be posted automatically in the other site, says google+?", The question asks for either direction if I understand correctly.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. A link isn't much of an answer, though.