# Posting in Google+ that is automatically reposted on Facebook

Tags: facebook, google-plus

How can I post in Google+ that is automatically reposted on Facebook?

Are there any browser extensions for this in Google Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oenpjldbckebacipkfbcoppmiflglnib).

You can also have a look at [this article](http://www.techtipsgeek.com/share-posts-in-both-google-plus-and-facebook-at-the-same-time/14326/) for a more generic solution

Comment: Sorry, this Chrome extension doesn't work for new Google+ site :(